# how can I fetch arrays of the object in an object in vue or javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an object in my Vue instance with the name of items

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selected: "",
      items: {
        item1: [{ selected: "", inputType: "", inputTarget: "" }],
        item2: [{ selected: "", inputType: "", inputTarget: "" }]
      },
      textarea: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    selectboxAction(index) {
      this.items.item1.forEach(val => {
        if (val.selected.toLowerCase() === "file") {
          this.$refs.inputData[index].type = "file";
        } else {
          this.$refs.inputData[index].type = "text";
        }
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

how can I fetch an array of it, I want to put some condition over every item, but it could have  item more than 2 items, maybe in the future it reaches 100

as you can see in selectboxAction method, I was able to fetch only one item which is item1 in this case

how can I fetch all of the arrays from items, not just one `item1`

Comment: If you want all the nested array of objects, you can just do `Object.values(this.items)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

Comment: `this.items.item1.forEach(...);` => `for (let key in this.items) { this.items[key].forEach(...); }`, e.g. https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZM707NdQVKE9iJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you format your data using a [computed getter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) and use Object.keys as others have suggested.

```
get itemsArray() {
  return Object.keys(this.items).map((key) =>
    return this.items[key];
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of naming your 'items' properties 'item1', 'item2', etc, it would be better make 'items' an array and add an 'id' property to each 'items' object:

```
  data() {
    return {
      selected: "",
      items: [
        { id: 1, selected: "", inputType: "", inputTarget: "" },
        { id: 2, selected: "", inputType: "", inputTarget: "" }
      ],
      textarea: ""
    };
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like

```
 methods: {
    selectboxAction(index) {
      Object.keys(this.items).forEach(val => {
        this.items[val].forEach(item => {
        if (item.selected.toLowerCase() === "file") {
          this.$refs.inputData[index].type = "file";
        } else {
          this.$refs.inputData[index].type = "text";
        }
       });
      });
    }
  }
```